Terraform - publish Lambda only when there are changes
I'm having trouble configuring my AWS Lambda feature in Terraform. Right now, the following configuration works so that the function deployment flies every time, even when I don't have any changes made to it. This is because the source_code_hash is generated different from the previous one.
Do you have any idea how to make it better so that terraform detects changes in the code and only when it finds them does it then do its deployment?
data "archive_file" "parser_service" {
  type = "zip"

  source_dir  = "${path.module}/xxx"
  output_path = "${path.module}/xxx.zip"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "s3_object" {
  bucket = var.lambda_bucket
  key    = "lambda_parser_${var.node_env}.zip"
  source = "${path.module}/lambda_parser_${var.node_env}.zip"

  etag = filemd5(data.archive_file.parser_service.output_path)
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "parser_function" {
  function_name = var.lambda_name
  handler       = "xxx/main.handler"
  role          = var.iam_role
  runtime       = var.runtime
  memory_size   = var.memory_size
  timeout       = var.timeout

  s3_bucket = var.lambda_bucket
  s3_key    = aws_s3_object.s3_object.key

  source_code_hash = filemd5("${path.module}/lambda_parser_${var.node_env}.zip")

  depends_on = [aws_s3_object.s3_object]
}

Thanks for any help!
#Edit
I was trying to use:
source_code_hash = aws_s3_object.s3_object.etag

but it generate me this error while i'm run terraform apply:
provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" produced an invalid new value for .source_code_hash: was 
│ cty.StringVal("ea34c83724a7cac5009bd03cb2388a33"), but now cty.StringVal("ce4f3d0e888dddf1d20d1dbeb36938e8-10").


If your usage is correct and the provider is at the latest version then you should report that error to the tracker since the provider should be preventing that error from occurring (unless usage is incorrect in which case provider should probably be raising an error during validation).

The zip file hash is always going to change, due to the nature of how zip files work, so the S3 file will always get updated, and the Lambda function will always get redeployed. I've encountered this same thing myself. I ended up moving the zip file creation out of Terraform, into a separate build process that I would only run when there were actual changes to the Lambda function I needed to deploy.

@MarkB thanks for answer, i think about this same, Your build process was a part of the CI/CD or you've just sh script to create zip and push to s3?

You can get the hash from the output_base64sha256 output property of the archive_file data and then use it in your aws_lambda_function definition:
source_code_hash = data.archive_file.parser_service.output_base64sha256
Also, because your aws_lambda_file is already referencing  the aws_s3_object resource, the depends_on block is redundant.

I did it already and it works, but i still have discrepancies between s3_object even when there is no changes, i know that each zip file will generate always a new sha, but is there a way to regenerate this s3_object only when content has been changed?
